# jQuery 'has no method' error when attempting to render a template

Tags: jquery, templates

This is probably a dumb question, but I've been beating my head at it long enough.

I have a template built for use with jQuery .tmpl(). I can successfully select it with $("#templateId"), but calling `$("#templateId").tmpl(data)` results in a `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tmpl'`.

It looks like an issue with jQuery's method definitions, but tmpl is in the core, right? Is there a conflict with UI?

Running jQuery 1.6.4, UI 1.8.16

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it's an officially supported plugin, you can get the latest [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl)

Comment: @genesis So close man, but look down in the next box, the one where it says `This documentation topic concerns the jQuery Templates plugin (jquery-tmpl), which can be downloaded from: http://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl` :P

Comment: Ahhh... I must've had the wrong 'template' plugin when I attempted that earlier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're not using the `tmpl` plugin required: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl

Answer (score 0):

tmpl is a plugin, you need to download/install it before use it. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/